# Missing commits after switching back and forth between branches

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am new to git so please bear with me. On my local repo, I've been working on this branch for a while with many commits. I haven't really pushed in a while because I am the only one working on this project. Today I finally decided it might be time to merge the development branch into the master branch so I did a `git checkout master`. (I did a `git status` before and nothing needed to be added).

After switching to master, I decided to go back to my development branch with a `git checkout check_pburst` (`check_pburst` is my development branch's name) but now I can only see the commits up to the time I pushed. I have a feeling I'm on a remote tracking branch (maybe?). `git log` shows that a lot of my commits aren't shown. Is there a way I can see the commits past the time I pushed? I wish I could give you guys more info but I accidentally closed git bash and now the messages I got aren't view-able anymore.

How do I recover my latest commits?

Update: After looking into this issue more, I did a `git branch` and saw only two branches (which makes sense). I then did a `git checkout tab tab` and it listed more branches but none of those branches had my latest commits. Then I did a `git reflog` which showed my latest commit. I did a `git checkout 25edfe8`. I then did a `git branch` and noticed that my latest commit was on the branch `Detached HEAD at 25edfe8`

Comment: Are you certain that you really made the commits in the first place?  Had you been wisely doing `git push origin dev_branch_name` often to ensure that you have a backup of your work on another computer?  Commits in Git usually don't vanish like gym socks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have done `git add -A` and `git commit -m 'message'` many times.... But no I've only pushed once on this dev branch. And that was a long time ago!

Comment: The commit should be there...somewhere, ideally in the branch in which you committed.  Do you recall doing a `git log` ever and seeing these commits?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yup I've done `git log` plenty of times and seen my commits. So I'm 99% sure there in git somewhere. But now after today when I do a `git log` I DON'T see my latest commits

Comment: Type `git branch` and let us know what you see.  Maybe you committed to another branch unbeknownst to you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've done that and I see two branches: master and my branch called `check_pburst`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108197/discussion-between-dzhao-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussions, it became evident that you had been working in a detached head state rather than in your feature branch `check_pburst`.  The standard solution to bring commits from a detached state into an actual branch is first create a branch.  Do the following from your detached state:

```
git checkout -b check_pburst_detached
```

At this point, you have created a bona-fide Git branch containing all the stray commits which you made.  It would be prudent at this point to backup your work by pushing this to the remote:

```
git push origin check_pburst_detached
```

If at any subsequent point you make a mistake or get lost, you can always "reset" back to this branch, which you know contains all your commits.

Since you want to actually retain all the detached commits in your feature branch, you best option might be to rebase `check_pburst_detached` on `check_pburst` and then fast-forward the latter with the former:

```
git checkout check_pburst_detached
git rebase check_pburst
```

Complete the rebase and then fast-forward merge `check_pburst_detached` onto `check_pburst`:

```
git checkout check_pburst
git merge check_pburst_detached
```

This merge should have zero conflicts, as the `check_pburst_detached` branch should be ahead of `check_pburst`.  You can verify that your feature branch `check_pburst` indeed has the commits which went missing.